# using foreach and multiple insert rows?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm a newbie from C# and I'm currently using C# vs 2013 and MS access database..I'm trying to do the mulitple inserts and at the same time trying to attempt foreach..
I have 2 tables in access

first table

```
EID  ------ FirstName
10175-- random names
10176-- random names
10177-- random names
10178 --random names
10179 --random names
10180 --random names
```

2nd table

```
index--- EID-----Date(index is autonumber type)
1-------10175----10/10/2014
2-------10175----10/11/2014
3-------10175----10/12/2014
4-------10175----10/13/2014
5-------10175----10/14/2014
6-------10175----10/15/2014
7-------10175----10/16/2014
8-------10175----10/17/2014
9-------10175----10/18/2014
10------10175----10/10/2014
```

what I wanted to happen was when I click a button I want to insert 10 record dates on 2nd table FOR EACH EID on the first table..here's my code for the loop 10 records for 10175

```
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        int ctr = 0;
        int counter;
        counter = int.Parse(TimeIntxt.Text);//I just use textbox for test i want this to be autogenerate based on the number of EID on first table 
        String counter2;
        for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
        {
            counter++;
            counter2 = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(ctr + 1).ToString();

            command10.CommandText = "insert into EmployeeData (EID,DateIn) values('" + counter + "','" + counter2 + "')";
            command10.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("successfully created");
        connection.Close();
```

Very much thankful for those who will help me..I'm sorry if my english is not really fluent Y.Y

Comment: It sounds like you will want to use an `OleDbDataReader` to loop through the rows in the first table. See the related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12081111/2144390) for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connection.Open()
OleDBCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = "SELECT EID From Table";

using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr.read())
    {
        //new connection
        for(var i = 0;i < 10;i++)
        {  
            //insert (int)dr["EID"] into 2nd table
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why is it that SqlDataReader in my code that you give is still on red lines below i know that means an error did i miss something there?

Comment: tried to changed SqlDataReader with OleDbDataReader and dr.read() becomes red this time

Comment: by the way how do i use using block?

Comment: You really need to look at the documentation for the OleDbDataReader object and find the appropriate methods to use.  I was really just giving you a general idea on how to structure your code to accomplish what you wanted, not write the code for you.