# Populate stored procedure result to a List<T>

Tags: c#

Is there a way to map the results of a stored procedure to a generic list instead of a dataset/datatable?

Currently I follow these steps:

1. Execute stored procedure
2. Take the result in Dataset
3. Populate list from the Dataset.

Is there a way to eliminate step (2).

```
OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand();
cm.Connection = AccessConnection();
cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cm.CommandText = "seltblContacts";

OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cm);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);

List<tblContacts> LstFile = new List<tblContacts>();

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    tblContacts t;

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        t = PopulateContacts(dr);
        LstFile.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a **stored procedure** - a procedure **stored** inside your database. It has nothing to do with a *store* ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes of course you can do that - just execute your command and get back a **reader**, and then iterate over the rows in the result set and build up your objects:

```
using (OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand())
{
     cm.Connection = AccessConnection();
     cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cm.CommandText = "seltblContacts";

     List<tblContacts> LstFile = new List<tblContacts>();

     using (OleDbReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader()) 
     {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            tblContacts contact = new tblContacts();

            // here, set the properties based on your columns from the database
            contact.FirstName = reader.GetString(0);    
            contact.LastName = reader.GetString(1);
            // etc.

            LstFile.Add(contact);
        }

        reader.Close();
     }

     return LstFile;    
}
```

For details on `OleDbReader` and how to use it, [see this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081111/getting-values-back-from-oledbdatareader-reading-from-access-database) or find tons of tutorials and samples online using Bing or Google.

Comment: Is this faster than my approach?

Comment: This will be tough to maintain. In future if there are any addition/subtraction of Columns, reader.GetString() will need special attention. The order of columns also may change.

Comment: Yes, this is **MUCH** faster - basically, this is what the `OleDbAdapter` does under the covers - but without any of the overhead of creating a `DataSet` - just to throw it away at the end of the processing

Comment: Yes, this is maintenance-intensive. If you want to avoid this, use an ORM (like Entity Framework) that basically does all of this for you and you don't have to write (and maintain!) that code!

Comment: It's always a question of **trade-off** - either you get the best performance - but the code you need to write and maintain is painful and work-intense - or you get a quick'n'easy solution with little or no code - but then your performance suffers. You can't have it all - one or the other - it's up to you to decide which one is more important to you.

Comment: FYI, IDbDataReader has a string indexer based on column (`reader["fieldName"]`) so there's no need to access the fields based on a numeric index.